# Retrieve documents from Firestore sequentially

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of timestamped posts in FireStore, Am planing to retrieve 10 posts at a time(query), how can I start the query ***n+1*** right from where the query ***n*** ended ?

if query n result was documents with index range(300-310), then query n+1 would result with documents(311-321)

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is to use StartFrom Method, passing the last received document snapshot to it.
This overload is not mentioned at the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#startAt).

Comment: For the guide on pagination (based on `startAt` and other order/filter methods), see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors